# Pandas: complex aggregation issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am having this `Dataframe`

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'person':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3, 4], 'area':['A','B','A','A',
'C','C','C','C'], 'job type':['politics', 'expert', 'politics', 'politics', 'law
yer','judge', 'judge', 'lawyer']})

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  area  job type  person
0    A  politics       1
1    B    expert       1
2    A  politics       2
3    A  politics       2
4    C    lawyer       3
5    C     judge       3
6    C     judge       3
7    C    lawyer       4
```

I would like for persons in area `C` to be able to see if they have been both a lawyer and a judge and output the result to a second `DataFrame`, something like

```
   person  jobtype
0       1  None
1       2  None
3       3  LAWYER_JUDGE
4       4  None
```

Is this possible with pandas?

Comment: You want to group based on area as well? If so can you explain what happens if a person was lawyer in one area and judge in another area?

Comment: No I want to zoom in on area C and then check is someone was both a lawyer and a judge

Comment: i don't understand, *zoom in* ?

Comment: Yes I mean *concentrate* on area C

Comment: If so, why do you have person `1` or person `2` in the result? they were never part of area 'C' ?

Comment: @YannisP.-- Are you looking for all persons list and jobtyple column filled with true if that person has both lawyer and judge?

Comment: @JohnGalt This could also work I think

Comment: @AnandSKumar Those are part of the data I m having but that could go if this makes things easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to find people who have both lawyer and judge

```
In [43]: zoomin = lambda x: None if len(np.setdiff1d(['judge', 'lawyer'], x['job type'])) else 'lawyer_judge'

In [44]: df.groupby('person').apply(zoomin)
Out[44]:
person
1            None
2            None
3    lawyer_judge
4            None
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks John it works like a charm! Can I generalise to add the actual unique job value instead of None? Thank you anyway?